# LIBGDX not rendering a sprite made by a class

Tags: java, class, libgdx, sprite, render

OK. Lets dive straight in.
I'm using LibGdx to create a basic Tower Defense game but Im having some issues. I have my Screen class and I also have a class for a basic enemy. Here is the class for the enemy:

```
private int segment = 1;


Texture img;
public towerBasic(){
    img = new Texture("towerBasic.png");
    setTexture(img);
    setX(10);
    setY(10);
}

public void update(){
    if(segment == 1){
        System.out.println(getY());
        setY(getY()+1);
    }

}
```

}

It looks fine (to me.. please let me know if you see a error). Also the class name is "towerBasic". That was the sprite class I am trying to render. Here is the screen class (Map1) that I am trying to render it on:

```
private SpriteBatch batch;

public Texture maptex;
public Sprite map;

public towerBasic tower;

MainGame game;

public Map1(MainGame game){
    this.game = game;

}

@Override
public void show() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    maptex = new Texture("map1.png");

    map = new Sprite(maptex);

    tower = new towerBasic();


}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    tower.update();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();
    map.draw(batch);
    tower.draw(batch);


    batch.end();

}
```

I run the launcher, the correct screen starts and renders the background image correctly, except the enemy is not being drawn... Any insights?

Comment: from which class does your towerBasic class inherit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **create** base object with passing *Texture* instance to it - then you can assign it to the *Texture* field if it is necessary.

In a nut shell your **towerBasic** class should look like:

```
Texture img;

public towerBasic(){
    super(new Texture("towerBasic.png"));

    img = this.getTexture();

    ...
```

Comment: Ok trying it out now.

Comment: Yes thankyou so much! It has worked. As soon as i have 15 rep ill upvote :D